# VBA Using InStr() match a record in Table A to a record in Table B, then update a field in Table A with a value from the matching Table B record

Tags: ms-access

I'm having one of those days where everything has gone blank.
Simply - I have two tables, called WordyA and WordyB.
WordyA contains a field called 'Answer' and may contain values such as 'Excellent, brilliant, fantastic, etc'
WordyA also contains an analysis field called 'Analysis' that will insert a 'common value' from the second table, WordyB.
WordyB is a sort of directory, and had two fields - 'Word' containing 'Excellent etc' above, but also a code field called 'Analysis'.
The idea being, all the words above might be classed as code 'A'.  If the words in the WordyB table were 'Very Good' or 'Pretty Good' they would have a code of 'B'
I want to cycle through the WordyA records and assign a code letter from the WordyB table.  So we can produce tables and analysis with all the type 'A' responses, compared to call the type 'B' responses.

I used the following VBA code, and played around with it so much I can't see the wood for the trees.  So even simple suggestions would help!

I'm using nested DO statements to try to run through each record at a time. (There are only 30 'answers' in WordyB so it shouldn't be too process hungry)

```
Dim findwhat As String
Dim outanalysis As String
Dim findresult As Integer
Dim mresult As String
Dim lineid As Integer

Set rsanswer = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("WordyA")
rsanswer.MoveFirst

Do Until rsanswer.EOF Or rsanswer.BOF
    lineid = rsanswer![IDData]
    findin = rsanswer![Answer]
    mresult = rsanswer![Analysis]
    Set rsdirect = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("WordyB")
    rsdirect.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsdirect.EOF Or rsdirect.BOF
        outanalysis = rsdirect![DLetter]
        findwhat = rsdirect![DWord]
        If InStr(findin, findwhat) Then
            Rem CurrentDb.Execute "update WordyA Set mresult = outanalysis where IDData = " & lineid
        End If
    rsdirect.MoveNext
Loop
rsanswer.MoveNext
Loop
rsanswer.Close
rsdirect.Close
```

My version on the IF statement either reports a missing clause or just doesn't do anything.

I don't think the 'update' option I have REM'd out above is right, looking for alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the value:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "update WordyA set mresult = '" & outanalysis & "' where IDData = " & lineid & ""
```

**Addendum**:

The field name is not `mresult` but `Analysis`, thus:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "update WordyA set Analysis = '" & outanalysis & "' where IDData = " & lineid & ""
```

However, use *DAO* as you have the table open and avoid the clumsy SQL:

```vb
Set rsanswer = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("WordyA")
Set rsdirect = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("WordyB")

rsanswer.MoveFirst
Do Until rsanswer.EOF Or rsanswer.BOF
    findin = rsanswer![Answer].Value
    rsdirect.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsdirect.EOF Or rsdirect.BOF
        findwhat = rsdirect![DWord].Value
        If InStr(findin, findwhat) Then
            rsanswer.Edit
            rsanswer!Analysis.Value = rsdirect![DLetter].Value
            rsanswer.Update
        End If
        rsdirect.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsanswer.MoveNext
Loop
rsanswer.Close
rsdirect.Close
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, thanks for the line, unfortunately it compiles ok, but when I run the function I get a 'Too few parameters :  Expected 1' error message.

Comment: Then a table name, field name, or parameter name is missing or misspelled.

Comment: Thanks Gustav.  Yep, that's pretty much where I got to.  It should work, I keep checking everything, but I can't get the execute line to work.  I've been around and around the same problem all day.

Comment: The best result so far I changed to code to separate the currentdb.execute and added the query separately -  ie added :  doit = "UPDATE WordyA SET mresult = 'A' where IDData = 1""" and replaced the execute line with :  CurrentDb.Execute doit, dbFailOnError  But it still falls over at that line (the value used for IDDate comes up in the error message and changes if I alter the code to IDDate=2) All integers are numbers all strings are strings.  Scratching my head really.

Comment: It's the field name. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks Gustav you're a star.  Worked straight away. Sometimes you can't see what's right in front of you and the DAO version is much neater.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, why not just use a  join, and never bother to update the actual values?

I mean, I can have this:

[image]

So, above will allow me to translate any key word to whatever I want.

Hence a query like this:

[image]

Which of course is this:

```
SELECT tblA.ID, tblA.Answer, tblB.TransLateTo
FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON tblA.Answer = tblB.Answer;
```

And the output is this:

[image]

So, you NEVER need any code to update the translation.

And even better? If you decide over time to change the translate value, then all of your reports and queries will now work, and you have no need to write code to "maintain" these values over time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.  Normally I would use join.  But the information is coming from a data form, where the user wants a verbatim comment rather than a one word answer, so we get a lot of 'they were brilliant'.  We want to find the 'brilliant' bit, then see what that word was classified as - 'A'.  Same applies at the other end of the scale, ie 'they were bloody crap' etc etc.